# How to put overlay NSImageView and keep it at the top of a WebView?

Tags: animation, indexing, webview, nsimageview

How to put overlay view (NSImageView) and keep it at the top  in front of a WebView ( which runs core animation or  )?

Standard ordering in interface builder does not help.. imageview is shown in front of the webview but when i load the contents of webview with a  tag or only just an html opacity animation, suddently webview takeovers the top position and shows over the imageview.

Can't i do this?

Answer (score 3):

although two years passed, maybe this is solved by yourself or it no longer exists as a problem, i think an answer for this should be helpful for future viewers here :)

after found this question (even without replies below) http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/223499-core-animation-how-to-swicth-off-all-implicit-animations.html I found this single line

```
    [imageView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

will do the job. its because "a WebView seems to be using Core Animation layer-backed views"